# Ubuntu server in azure cloud: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting while restart apache

Tags: 14.04, sudo

I am creating a ubunu virtual machine in my azure cloud service and installed the lampp stack and phpmyadmin.

Instllation is completed without any problem and for accessing the phpmyadmin i have added the following line in `etc\apahe2\apache.conf` file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

But when i restart the apache after saving the file using the command `sudo service restart apache2` i will get the following error.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0` means you should change the ownership of `/etc/sudoers` from you to `root`. You cannot run `sudo` until it's fixed.

Can you boot to single-user mode, mount `/` r/w, then

```
chown -R root /etc/sudoers
```

I didn't use `sudo` because single-user mode is already `root` (`UID 0`). I used the `-R` to affect `/etc/sudoers` and everything under it